# Dynamic to create trigger to do insert, update and delete operation in sql server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

i have 100 tables in my database.

The tables are

```
Product 
Warehouse
inventoty
```

... etc

I want to write the trigger, for which table i want.

For example :

Product table i made any changes like update, delete or insert that changes stored into

Product_Log table.

Eg:

Product table

```
 ProductId   ProductName  Price
   M1         Tank           100
   M2         water          722
   M3         Lift           342
```

Product_Log table

```
 ProductId   ProductName  Price  
   M1         Tank           100
   M2         water          722
   M3         Lift           342
```

If i made any changes in Product table it automatic insert into Product_Log table.

Update Product set Productname = 'vat' where ProductId='M1'

Product table

```
  ProductId   ProductName  Price
   M1         VAT           100
   M2         water          722
   M3         Lift           342
```

Product_Log table

```
 ProductId   ProductName  Price  
   M1         Tank           100
   M2         water          722
   M3         Lift           342
   M1         Vat            1234
```

If i delete or update the row from Product that row also insert into Product_Log table.

Comment: "I want to write the trigger," - feel free. I don't see any attempt made so far...

Comment: What *particular* difficulties are you having currently?

Comment: @Mitch Wheat: Can you actually see who upvoted a post and who didn't? For obviously there *are* upvotes on some of the answers to the OP's earlier questions. (Just curious)

Comment: i did separately for insert,delete or update. but i don't know how to cover 3 things in one.

Comment: @Mitch Wheat: Ah yes, that information is open, I forgot about it, thanks.

Comment: Maybe you should post what you've got so far (your three separate triggers). That might help both to understand the problem better and to come up with an optimal solution.

Comment: Try below link
http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/01/27/adding-simple-trigger-based-auditing-to-your-sql-server-database.aspx
it define dynamically create triggers.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [sys.tables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187406.aspx) and [sys.columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176106.aspx) catalog views which provide you with the information about tables and their columns.

From this information you can write TSQL code to generate your insert/update/delete triggers.